# SUPEE 6788 Update and SALE page is gone

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My sale /special/ page no longer shows products after the SUPEE 6788 update. Any ideas how to fix it ?
As well as, new arrivals, best selling and recently viewed products also do not show.

Comment: Could you try reverting the patch applied and see if it works for you ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like some of your blocks are broken.
The patch adds 2 new whitelists for blocks to your admin under System > Permissions

Make sure that the block types you use for these pages are added under variables and blocks.

My setup:

VARIABLES:

- cms/block

BLOCKS:

- cms/block
- catalog/product_list

Update:

Found this toolbox: https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox
this let's you run an analyze script from SSH to figure out which blocks are not whitelisted yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to revert the patch you have applied. As the new Magento patch is quite extensive in security you have got to make sure that:

1. Your theme (if your using one) - has the latest update in place
2. Your extensions which you use are also compatible with the recent changes
3. Once you can confirm that everything is up to date, you can install the SUPEE 6788 patch.

If you want to debug the errors open the following:

```
/var/report
```

Send the contents of the file which contains the errors. To create a new error file, simply go to the page you getting the error at and the directory will update.

**@UPDATE**

Also, please note that new version of Magento now includes a white list of allowed blocks or directives. If a module or extension uses blocks like {{block type="catalog/product_list"}} in CMS pages, and the directives are not on this list, you will need to add them to your database.

You can add them manually in the Magento backend under System > Permissions > Variables and System > Permissions > Blocks once, if you already upgraded your Magento to version 1.9.2.2. Add 'catalog/product_list' and 'cms/pages' and products to the whitelist.

Also, don't forget to flush cache!